# Simple LINQ to XML query

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

This one is my simple XML

```
 Dim Xml = <BODY ID="1">
   <HEAD1>
    <Eyes type="S" l="1" f="1"></Eyes>
   </HEAD1>
   <HEAD2>
    <Eyes type="S" l="1" f="1"></Eyes>
   </HEAD2>
   </BODY>
```

How can i write a LINQ query to return as result the following?

```
HEAD1
HEAD2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you the answer in C# (and try to convert it to VB.Net)

```
var result = from element in xml.Root.Elements()
             select element.Name;
```

this *may* be VB.Net code:

```
Dim result = From element In xml.Root.Elements Select element.Name
```

Comment: @Chocol8 Yes, it gets the root element of the document. You can also use `xml.Element("BODY")` <- again is C#

Comment: Got it! Dim result = From element In Xml.Elements Select element.Name.LocalName